# excel multiple paste specials

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to paste values of Columns `1`,`2`, & `4` and Formulas of Column `3` only.

I can get either or to work with all 4 columns but I am not sure how to do only 1 column with `.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats`

```
Sub FindData() 'Find Both
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim datasheet As Worksheet   'data copied from
Dim reportsheet As Worksheet 'data pasted to
Dim partone As String        'search criteria 1
Dim parttwo As String        'search criteria 2
Dim finalrow As Integer      'find last used row
Dim i As Integer             'row counter

'set variables
Set datasheet = Sheet2
Set reportsheet = Sheet4
partone = reportsheet.Range("E6").Value
parttwo = reportsheet.Range("F6").Value

'clear old data from reort sheet
reportsheet.Range("A10:D110").ClearContents

'goto datasheet and start searching and copying
datasheet.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'loop through the rows to find matching records
For i = 10 To finalrow
If Cells(i, 5) = partone And Cells(i, 6) = parttwo Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Copy
    reportsheet.Select
    Range("A101").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    datasheet.Select
    End If
Next i

reportsheet.Select
Range("E9:F9").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Add an If clause to your current If to check if i=3?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you don't need to keep using `someSheet.Select`, using the worksheet variable directly is safer and quicker. E.g. `finalrow = datasheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`. If you don't want to keep referencing the same worksheet, use a `With` statement block.

Comment: @SteveES if you are giving advice, give it correct, your `finalrow` is not fully qualified, it needs to be `finalrow = datasheet.Cells(datasheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0):

This gives me Values only on Column `4`. Opposite of what I asked but gives me same result.

```
For i = 10 To finalrow
If Cells(i, 5) = partone And Cells(i, 6) = parttwo Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Copy
    reportsheet.Select
    Range("A101").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    datasheet.Select
    End If
If Cells(i, 5) = partone And Cells(i, 6) = parttwo Then
    Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 4)).Copy
    reportsheet.Select
    Range("A101").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    datasheet.Select
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will copy the values only from column A:B and D, and Paste them to `reportsheet`, and will copy only the formulas from column C.

**Note**: you have too many `Select` and unqualified objects, the object in the code below are fully qualified with their worksheets using the `With` statement.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindData() 'Find Both

Dim datasheet As Worksheet   'data copied from
Dim reportsheet As Worksheet 'data pasted to
Dim partone As String        'search criteria 1
Dim parttwo As String        'search criteria 2
Dim finalrow As Long      'find last used row
Dim i As Long             'row counter

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'set variables
Set datasheet = Sheet2
Set reportsheet = Sheet4

With reportsheet
    partone = .Range("E6").Value
    parttwo = .Range("F6").Value

    'clear old data from reort sheet
    .Range("A10:D110").ClearContents
End With

'  start searching and copying from datasheet
With datasheet
    finalrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'loop through the rows to find matching records
    For i = 10 To finalrow
        If .Range("E" & i).Value = partone And .Range("F" & i).Value = parttwo Then

            Dim firstEmptyCell As Range
            Set firstEmptyCell = reportsheet.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            firstEmptyCell.Resize(1, 2).Value = .Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Value
            firstEmptyCell.Offset(, 3).Value = .Range("D" & i).Value
            .Range("C" & i).Copy
            firstEmptyCell.Offset(, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
        End If
    Next i
End With

'reportsheet.Select ' <-- not sure why you need it
'Range("E9:F9").Select  ' <-- not sure why you need it
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @Matt Taylor have you tried my code above ? any feedback ?